# Error with strings when creating filename in Matlab on hpc

Tags: matlab, hpc

I am running a matlab script on an hpc which save various variables using the following command:

```
fname = char(['~/Documents/MATLAB/PROCESSING/', strtrim(participant), '/', strtrim(participant),strtrim(task), 'PRO.mat']);
```

However, I get the following error in that it can't find the folder as long spaces are added to the variable 'participant'.

```
Error using save
Cannot create '                                       HC_s02
resting                                 PRO.mat
' because '/home/eb857/Documents/MATLAB/PROCESSING/HC_s02
' does not exist.

Error in LUMO_finalPipeline (line 163)
    save(fname, 'dat', '-v7.3');
```

I have tried doing the following:

```
participant = strrep(participant, ' ', '');
task = strrep(task, ' ', '');
```

But I still get the error. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: While there may be a workaround (I think a space can be given as `\ `) I would 10000000% suggest you avoid problems by simply not having spaces in your paths. It will make you life much easier. This is the reason `_` is often present in filenames., e.g. `patient_id_123_sleep.mat`

Comment: The `save` function will not make folders for you, if you want to save to a new directory (`HC_s02`) then you have to use something like `mkdir('/home/eb857/Documents/MATLAB/PROCESSING/HC_s02')` first